# Self-Adjoint Operators

Tags: operator-theory, adjoint-operators

If an Operator $L$ is defined as $Lu=u''$ and $a_1u(0)+b_1u'(0)+c_1u(1)+d_1u'(1)=0$ along with $a_2u(0)+b_2u'(0)+c_2u(1)+d_2u'(1)=0$, then for what values of $a_1,b_1,c_1,etc$ is the operator self-adjoint?  Obviously, I see that the operator L is symmetric after expanding it out via integration by parts.  Then, I need to assert that $[u'v-uv']$ evaluated at $x=0$ to $x=1$ (boundary upon which this is defined) is equivalent to zero.  Any idea how to go about this?  I feel like I don't have enough equations to solve for those constants....

Comment: Of course you do not have enough equations! There is a continuous family of solutions. What you get is an if and only if condition.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean there is a lot of solutions to your problem.

Comment: Have you calculated the adjoint of $L$?

Comment: Yes, given <v,Lu>, the adjoint <L*v,u> = integral (v'' * u) from 0 to 1 over x.  This is true only if u' * v - u * v' (defined from 0 to 1) vanishes.

Comment: How can I use this information?